# Playing mp3 files with crosswalk

Tags: android, gradle, crosswalk-runtime, crosswalk

I have the following in my `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
    productFlavors {
        armv7 {
            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", ""
            }
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:21.51.546.6'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
}
```

When running my project it works just fine! The issue that I am having is with crosswalk, where it isn't playing mp3 files. We need the app to play mp3 files. I believe that I have read that I need to make a custom build of crosswalk enabling support for mp3's. I am not sure what I would need to do to accomplish this though.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the answer? I've been trying with no luck

Comment: No, What I did read though is you have to build crosswalk yourself and enable mp3 due to licensing.

Comment: Yeah I read that as well, it just wasn't very clear as to how to do that. Thanks!